# Do we use "its" or "their" with a collective noun?

Tags: pronouns

For example, which sentence is correct?

> The House's minority makes its voices heard.

or

> The House's minority makes their voices heard.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon whether the members of the collective noun are acting as a unit or acting individually.  In this case, given that we are talking about a single minority, presumably acting in concert, I would lean toward "its".  The use of the plural "voices" complicates that interpretation slightly, but I think it still works.  However, if the plural "their" were used, then the collective noun should also take the plural verb "make".

> "The jury renders its verdict."
>
> "The jury eat their lunches."

I suppose a rule of thumb here is to think about what pronoun you would replace the subject with.  "It renders its verdict." "They eat their lunches."  If you think "It makes its voices heard" fits the meaning better than "They make their voices heard", then it should be "its".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you are using British English or American English. British English, as far as I understand it, considers a noun-for-a-group-of-individuals to be *plural*. American English considers such a noun to be *singular*.

So, if you are using British English, you say: "The House's minority make their voices heard." If you're using American English, you say: "The House's minority makes its voice heard."

HOWEVER, if you *do* say "The House's minority make their voices heard" to Americans, it will probably be presumed you are eliding words: "The [members of the] House's minority make their voices heard."

Personally, I'd rewrite the sentence to "The members of the House's minority make their voices heard," and avoid the potential for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

They are both right, depending on your reference.

If you use House Minority as a **singular** proper noun, you would use:

> The House Minority makes its voice heard.

If you are referring to the House's minority as an informal group of individuals, you would use:

> The House's minority makes their voices heard.

Comment: For the plural wouldn't it be:  ***make their*** (no **'s'** on *make*)?

Comment: That's a good question.  I've heard it both ways.  I think it's regional.

Answer (score -2):

I personally feel `The House's minority makes its voices heard` is right because minority is a group, which is singular, hence its.

Comment: I thought so too, but have seen the sentence written with "their."

Comment: Under what occasions would "their" be correct?